# Reloading jQuery Scripts on image click

Tags: jquery, image, lightbox, switching

I'm building a webpage at the moment with a content switcher than will contain a lightbox. my problem at the moment is that the lightbox works on load, but when I switch content and switch back again it doesn't function.

I'm assuming that I will need to reload the code once I switch back to the content with the lightbox in it. is there a way that I can have the jQuery script run once on load (initial page) and then reload itself every time I switch back to the content? the link to switch content is an image. Can anybody help me? I can't seem to get a click function to work.

Comment: Any specifics, particularly which lightbox script? Might be a function you can call.  Also, seconded @SnippedSpace's comment.

Comment: yeah, its the colorbox script im using. does anyone have an example of how .live is used? or how i could implemnt this script? im new to jquery so please treat me like a 100% newbie